# PHP date_add is alias of DateTime::add, but who calls who internally?

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, datediff, dateadd

Like `date_add` there are many functions `date_diff`, `date_format` etc having a corresponding alias in `DateTime` class.

Do you know if internally `DateTime::add` calls `date_add` or vice versa?

And just to make sure: is `DateTime` class compiled internally in PHP, isn't' it? I mean when I call `DateTime` class, am I calling code that does not need to be parsed 1st by PHP like one of my .php file?!

Comment: Why do you want to know this - out of curiosity, or for a specific use case?

Comment: It's the same code. It can be shared as procedural function and method by virtue of the `PHP_ME_MAPPING` macro.

Comment: @Pekka: cause I have `MyDate class` (prior to 5.3 there wasn't a date class) and I would like to know if it's smarter to extend the built in `DateTime class` with some methods provided by `MyDate class` or to simply call `date_add`, `date_diff` etc from within my `MyDate class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime extension is written in C. Consequences are:

- It's loaded before execution of any PHP script. So answer is no, it doesn't need to be parsed by the engine.
- C obviously doesn't support objects. Classes are usually mocked upon structs and functions. So DateTime::add translates to date_add with according reference to the "object".